# how to check the expiration date with a cron job?

Tags: php, cron

I'm making a web application, how to check the expiration date in the database with a cron job. I have a column expiration date and the availability of class .. how to check the availability of classes in accordance with the expiration date. then displays the data classes available in the combo box ... please help, I do not have such a good logic

Comment: Post an attempt first and we'll try and help you out. Or read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `in the combo box`? What do you mean by that? CRONs don't display any data.